# My tab menus exit the page width

Tags: html, css, web, menu, nowrap

So I'm editting the CSS and the tab menu has a whitespace: nowrap property, which means it doesn't overlap but it ends up exiting the page. Setting the width of the tab menu itself does nothing even with !important and hierarchy CSS.

Looks like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbmhg.jpg

When I do whitespace: pre, or any of the others they end up overlapping.

Comment: Can you give us your code? I can't extract it out of the image.

Comment: Give the parent `overflow: auto` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a floated list. Can't be certain without looking a code, but you may need to either extend the width of the containing div or clear the float.